# Hold'em hybrid dealing

Tags: home-game

There's an interesting Greek poker game with community cards called the "double Cuckoo bird", which consists of three hole cards and five community cards, therefore resembling "Hold'em" games.

All three hole cards are usable simultaneously, and a minimum of two hole cards must be used anyway (just like in Omaha, and unlike in Texas), resulting in that 2 or 3 board cards out of 5 must be used respectively, in each case.

The game has been traditionally dealt in five betting rounds (3 first with one hole card for each player, plus one community card on the board, and last 2 rounds each consisting of just one community card).

If I'm not seriously mistaken, it can eventually produce, on the average, stronger hands than Omaha, or Texas Hold'em.

If you were to deal that game in "Hold'em" mode (i.e. dealing the 3 hole cards first, as a first betting round), how would you deal the board?

Would you do it 3+1+1 (just like Texas and Omaha, i.e. four betting rounds), or, given the massive 3 fully useable hole cards, would you opt for 2+1+2 (still four betting rounds), or maybe 2+1+1+1 (five betting rounds)?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think five betting rounds is too many for a good poker game (that's one reason I prefer Mississippi stud to traditional). But that's just my opinion. You should also always deal at least two cards in the first betting round, three even better. Lastly, the final betting round should be a single card so that hanging around with weak draws isn't too profitable.

In a game with three hole cards and 5 board cards, I would probably deal like Pineapple 3h-3b-1b-1b, or save the last hole card for the final bet and deal 2h-3b-2b-1h. I might also deal that last hole card face up in either case.